# Fitness sharing in DEAP

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm, sharing, fitness, deap

Is there any way to implement fitness sharing/niching using [DEAP](https://github.com/DEAP/deap)?  Specifically I'm looking for an implementation of the method defined [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.30.8270&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (Goldberg's fitness sharing) on page 98 of the pdf.  If you know of any other methods that are in DEAP, that would be useful as well.

Thanks

Comment: Note that this was [cross-posted](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/146821/9964) on the stats site.

Comment: The question was removed from the stats site.

Answer (score 1):

Write your own selection routine.
The default routines are at [deap/tools/selection.py](https://github.com/DEAP/deap/blob/master/deap/tools/selection.py) and might be useful as a guide to get started

For example:

```
def selYourSelectionRoutine(individuals, k):
    """Select the *k* best individuals among the input *individuals*.

    :param individuals: A list of individuals to select from.
    :param k: The number of individuals to select.
    :returns: A list containing the k best individuals.
    """
    return sorted(individuals, key=attrgetter("fitness"), reverse=True)[:k]
```

Then use it with the rest of deap as they prescribe:

```
toolbox.register("select", tools.selYourSelectionRoutine, yourargs)
```

I've got one that does something more like a probablistic selection based on relative fitness which I don't have the rights to, it's only about 10-15 lines of python—so it can be done, and isn't crazy difficult.

I'm not aware of any implementations of that specific selection routine that are publically available (yet).

Comment: The method described in the link involves modifying the fitness function, not the selection function.

Answer (score 0):

To do fitness sharing, you would have to define your own shared fitness function that depends on the entire population.

Assuming you already defined a `fitness` function, you could do the following:

```py
from scipy.spatial import distance_matrix

def sharing(distance, sigma, alpha):
    res = 0
    if distance<sigma:
        res += 1 - (distance/sigma)**alpha
    return res

def shared_fitness(individual, population, sigma, alpha):
    num = fitness(individual)[0]

    dists = distance_matrix([individual], population)[0]
    tmp = [sharing(d, sigma, alpha) for d in dists]
    den = sum(tmp)

    return num/den,
```

This shared fitness will favor individuals with fewer neighbors. `sigma` is the radius in which neighbors will penalize an individual's shared fitness. If `sigma` is bigger, then your niches will be further away, and you risk missing a local maximum. If `sigma` is smaller, you need a larger population, and your algorithm will take longer to run. `alpha` indicates how strong the penalization for nearby neighbors is.

This shared fitness can then be registered in your toolbox like a regular fitness.

```
population = toolbox.population()
toolbox.register('evaluate', shared_fitness, population=population, sigma=0.1, alpha=1.)
```

After that, you can use a standard algorithm like $\mu + \lambda$, that will select offspring based on their fitness, to get niching.